# How to use the same source from PhoneGap Build and PhoneGap Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cross-platform, cordova, adt

Anyone might be notice there is a diffrence in PhoneGap Build and PhoneGap develop in Eclipse. I want to develop based on PhoneGap Build to support for Android and iPhone. However to do debugging in Android I need to setup Eclipse project which is differ than PhoneGap Build.

For example, the index.html location is in the root in Build while it is in asset/www in Eclipse. There is a config.xml in Build while I need to configure it in AndroidManifest.xml for Eclipse.

How can I use the same source for developing PhoneGap Build while I can debug it in Android and my friend can debug in iPhone? Any useful folder structure?
I want to put in the same SVN/GIT repo and I dont want to duplicate the index.html, css, img, js files.

Answer (score 2):

On XCode you can easily change the location of the /www folder:

- On the left panel go to Targets -> Your App
- Double click on each shell script and change /www to the new location of your www folder.

This way you can have a folder structure like this:

```
/myapp/android (android project files)
/myapp/ios (ios project files)
/myapp/www (source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly a PhoneGap Build integration, but you should look at Cordova: https://github.com/brianleroux/Cordova

Its a new tool for building one phonegap codebase for multiple platforms simultaneously.  It currently supports iOS and Android, and I would imagine further support will be available in the future.

Comment: Looking into the code. Hope this thing should PhoneGap Build be done. Otherwise I am forced to use different project for the different platform and manually make sure html,css and js in line outside from source control. So, PhoneGap Build have no meaning here.